# Application run as service is not appearing

Tags: visual-c++, windows-xp

I have two PCs and I'm logged in both with same user id(have the administration rights). I have installed the service on both PCs. I'm getting a strange issue:
1. If I remove both PCs from network then starting the service makes application appear on both the PCs.
2. If both PCs are in network then One PC shows application while on other it does not appear. however, if I check the task manager, application is running fine.

I find out following things:
1. On PC where application appears, active desktop is "Default"
2. On PC where application does not appear, active desktop is "Screen-Saver". I checked that non of the screen-saver are active and running on this pc. 
3. Now If I remove the PCs from network and re-connect then behaviour just got switched. I.e. where it was not working start appearing application but not on other PC.

Why one PC is in screen-saver mode while other in Default? Is this has to do with common login id? How can I work around this issue?

Comment: How do these services communicate? Via pipes, sockets what? How do they know about each other?

Answer (score 0):

These two services are independent of each other. These service createprocess() which invokes a VB application.

Another question I have is that if I'm not in N/w and run the service then it VB GUI appears properly. If I use remote desktop to start the service, the service appears properly but the VB GUI does not appear :-(
The active desktop at this moment is 'winlogon'. I'm not able to make the VB GUI visible if I give lpdesktop = "WinSta0\Desktop" or "WinSta0\winlogon" or "WinSta0\screen-saver". Please note that I'm accessing the system where service is physically running through remote desktop. 
Can someone let me know what I needs to do to make VB GUI appear remotely if I start the service remotely?